# Slide Out Navigation not working when I use revealToggle: method (SWRevealViewController Class)

Tags: objective-c, ios7, swrevealviewcontroller

I have successfully implemented SWRevealViewController Class in my project.

https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

But when I use revealToggle: method as my left bar button item action, it shows a complete black screen. The View is completely black.
But when I use rightRevealToggle: method, the view loads normally.

I'm including the code of AppDelegate.h,AppDelegate.m and Main view.

Slide out view is an empty view now. Just background colour changed.

Check it and let me know what is wrong.

Here is the screenshot of the project in simulator

http://i57.tinypic.com/mljpe9.png

### AppDelegate.h

```
//  AppDelegate.h
//  IndianBloodBank
//
//  Created by Roshith Balendran on 8/5/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Olympus. All rights reserved.
//


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class SWRevealViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SWRevealViewController *splitMenu;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;


@end
```

### AppDelegate.m

```
//  AppDelegate.m
//  IndianBloodBank
//
//  Created by Roshith Balendran on 8/5/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Olympus. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "HomePageViewController.h"
#import "SlideOutMenuViewController.h"
#import "SearchViewController.h"
#import "SearchViewController.h"
#import "AboutUsViewController.h"
#import "SponsorsViewController.h"
#import "HowToDonateViewController.h"
#import "EmergencyViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate()<SWRevealViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize splitMenu,window;

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = window;

    HomePageViewController *HPVC = [[HomePageViewController alloc]init];

    SlideOutMenuViewController *SOMVC = SOMVC = [[SlideOutMenuViewController alloc]init];




    UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:HPVC];
    UINavigationController *rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:SOMVC];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.125 green:0.122 blue:0.133 alpha:1]];

    SWRevealViewController *revealController= [[SWRevealViewController alloc]initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];

    revealController.rearViewRevealWidth = 120;
    revealController.rearViewRevealOverdraw = 120;
    revealController.bounceBackOnOverdraw = NO;
    revealController.stableDragOnOverdraw = YES;
    [revealController setFrontViewPosition:FrontViewPositionLeft];

    revealController.delegate=self;
    revealController.rightViewController = SOMVC;
    self.splitMenu = revealController;

    self.window.rootViewController = self.splitMenu;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;


}
```

### HomePageViewController.m

```
//  HomePageViewController.m
//  IndianBloodBank
//
//  Created by Roshith Balendran on 8/5/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Olympus. All rights reserved.
//

#import "HomePageViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "AboutUsViewController.h"
#import "SponsorsViewController.h"
#import "HowToDonateViewController.h"
#import "SearchViewController.h"

@interface HomePageViewController ()

@end

@implementation HomePageViewController

@synthesize btn1SearchBlood,btn2DonateNow;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent=NO;

    SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = [self revealViewController];

    [revealViewController panGestureRecognizer];
    [revealViewController tapGestureRecognizer];

    UIView* MenuButtonView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 20)];

    UIButton* MenuButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    MenuButton.frame=MenuButtonView.frame;
    [MenuButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"v1_menu-icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    MenuButton.tintColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    MenuButton.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
    MenuButton.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
    [MenuButton addTarget:revealViewController action:@selector(revealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [MenuButtonView addSubview:MenuButton];

    UIBarButtonItem *Menu=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:MenuButtonView];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=Menu;


}
```

Comment: If you never accept answers. No one will want to help you.

Comment: What..??!!! When did I say, I won't accept help.…??? I'm totally stuck and I'm asking for all your help...

Comment: I don't know what went wrong and I'm waiting for some experienced people to help me out... I don't understand, why you said I won't accept answers..!!!???

Comment: Sorry about my first question. I forgot to use initwithnibname. I found out about that after a while. I think, i accepted one as an answer... And for the second question, I didn't get any answers at all.. The guy asked me to rephrase my question... But by then, I played around and fixed the error.. I answered the question because no one did... And as for the this post, this is my 3rd question

Comment: It was my mistake, I didn't know that, I didn't accepted the answer to my first question. I just found out that I have to click the green tick icon to accept the answer...
It won't happen again, I didn't shoot and scoot.

I sincerely apologise guys... I should've done better than that...

Comment: And Ty, give the new comers a break. It was a mistake... 

I'm here to learn as well, not to berate or belittle anyone...

Now am I gonna receive the silent treatment...???
I don't know anything better to do now than apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem...

My trainer helped me to solve it.

Here is the edited code.

Thank you for all the help.

### AppDelegate.h

```
//  AppDelegate.h
//  IndianBloodBank
//
//  Created by Roshith Balendran on 8/5/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Olympus. All rights reserved.
//


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class SWRevealViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SWRevealViewController *splitMenu;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;


@end
```

### AppDelegate.m

```
//  AppDelegate.m
//  IndianBloodBank
//
//  Created by Roshith Balendran on 8/5/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Olympus. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "HomePageViewController.h"
#import "SlideOutMenuViewController.h"
#import "SearchViewController.h"
#import "SearchViewController.h"
#import "AboutUsViewController.h"
#import "SponsorsViewController.h"
#import "HowToDonateViewController.h"
#import "EmergencyViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate()<SWRevealViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize splitMenu,window;

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

//    self.window = window;

    HomePageViewController *HPVC = [[HomePageViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomePageViewController" bundle:nil];

    SlideOutMenuViewController *SOMVC ;

    SOMVC = [[SlideOutMenuViewController alloc]init];


    UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:HPVC];

//    UINavigationController *rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:SOMVC];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.078 green:0.09 blue:0.078 alpha:1]];

    splitMenu= [[SWRevealViewController alloc]initWithRearViewController:SOMVC frontViewController:frontNavigationController];

    splitMenu.rearViewRevealWidth = 120;
    splitMenu.rearViewRevealOverdraw = 120;
    splitMenu.bounceBackOnOverdraw = NO;
    splitMenu.stableDragOnOverdraw = YES;
    [splitMenu setFrontViewPosition:FrontViewPositionLeft];

    splitMenu.delegate=self;
    splitMenu.rightViewController = SOMVC;


    self.window.rootViewController = splitMenu;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;


}
```

### HomePageViewController.m

```
//  HomePageViewController.m
//  IndianBloodBank
//
//  Created by Roshith Balendran on 8/5/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Olympus. All rights reserved.
//

#import "HomePageViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "AboutUsViewController.h"
#import "SponsorsViewController.h"
#import "HowToDonateViewController.h"
#import "SearchViewController.h"

@interface HomePageViewController ()

@end

@implementation HomePageViewController
{
    SWRevealViewController *slideController;
}

@synthesize btn1SearchBlood,btn2DonateNow;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent=NO;

    slideController = [self revealViewController];

    //[revealViewController panGestureRecognizer];
   // [revealViewController tapGestureRecognizer];

    UIView* MenuButtonView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 20)];

    UIButton* MenuButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    MenuButton.frame=MenuButtonView.frame;
    [MenuButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"v1_menu-icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    MenuButton.tintColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    MenuButton.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
    MenuButton.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
    [MenuButton addTarget:slideController action:@selector(revealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [MenuButtonView addSubview:MenuButton];

    UIBarButtonItem *Menu=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:MenuButtonView];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=Menu;


}
```